# What is world building?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

- personal psychological architecture / brain wiring ?
- society ? Our connection with others?
- natural world ?
- what kinds of worlds ?

Comment: Worldbuilding is about building worlds and everything it contains. It is as simple as that. You can have a look at the tour http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour or some of our popular questions to have a better idea http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

Answer (score 2):

Worldbuilding is a forum for (real) people who want to build (fictional) worlds, and run into problems of certain types, mostly about the general background and not specific actions of specific characters.

- Society *can* be an issue if you find the right question, e.g. [What sort of punishment would replace fines in a post-scarcity society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/what-sort-of-punishment-would-replace-fines-in-a-post-scarcity-society)
- The natural world of the setting *can* be an issue if your find the right question, e.g. [Would a planet made completely of water be possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4969/would-a-planet-made-completely-of-water-be-possible)
- Psychology *can* be an issue, as long as it is not plot development, e.g. [Could an unusually long lived being continue to learn with the times?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11173/could-an-unusually-long-lived-being-continue-to-learn-with-the-times)

Comment: Creative and insightful reply.